# Is there any formal guideline that would indicate the necessity for adjustment for baseline when analysing change from baseline?

Tags: regression, modeling, predictor, pre-post-comparison

As in the topic. I saw many critical discussions along with mathematical explanation on why the baseline shouldn't (or mustn't) be employed as a covariate, when analysing the change from baseline. From the other side, certain regulators, like those pharmaceutical drug approval bodies, often demand it. Today I am not asking whether it is valid or not, but rather if you saw any formal document, that would address that? At least with a single sentence.

Answer (score 3):

I found one: *POINTS TO CONSIDER ON ADJUSTMENT FOR BASELINE COVARIATES*

issued by The European Agency for the Evaluation of Medicinal Products
Page 5

> II.7.     ‘Change from baseline’ analyses When the analysis is based
> on a continuous outcome there is commonly the choice of whether to
> use  the  raw  outcome  variable  or  the  change  from  baseline  as
> the  primary  endpoint.    Whichever of these endpoints is chosen, the
> baseline value should be included as a covariate in the primary
> analysis.  The use of change from baseline without adjusting for
> baseline does not  generally  constitute  an  appropriate  covariate
> adjustment.  Note  that  when  the  baseline  is  included  as  a
> covariate  in  the  model,  the  estimated  treatment  effects  are
> identical  for  both  ‘change  from  baseline’  and  the  ‘raw
> outcome’  analysis.    Consequently  if  the  appropriate  adjustment
> is done, then the choice of endpoint becomes solely an issue of
> interpretability.

https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/scientific-guideline/points-consider-adjustment-baseline-covariates_en.pdf

Also: *Adjusting for Covariates in Randomized Clinical Trials for Drugs and Biologics with Continuous Outcomes Guidance for Industry*
This is draft, but describes a common practice.

> Many clinical trials use a change from baseline as the primary outcome
> measure.  Even when 74 the outcome is measured as a change from
> baseline, the baseline value can still be used advantageously as a
> covariate

Issued by the FDA

https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/adjusting-covariates-randomized-clinical-trials-drugs-and-biologics-continuous-outcomes-guidance
And the summary here: http://onbiostatistics.blogspot.com/2019/05/fda-and-ema-guidance-on-adjusting-for.html

Also:
[image]
Source: [Guideline on adjustment for baseline covariates in clinical trials](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/scientific-guideline/guideline-adjustment-baseline-covariates-clinical-trials_en.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The FDA guideline has changed, but the overall idea remains:
https://www.fda.gov/media/148910/download

> Covariate adjustment is acceptable even if baseline covariates are
> strongly associated with each other (e.g., body weight and body mass
> index). However, adjusting for less redundant variables generally
> provides greater efficiency gains.

and

> When using this approach, adjusting for the baseline value rather than
> (or in addition to) defining the primary endpoint as a change from
> baseline is generally acceptable