# How is it possible, that statisticians have OPPOSITE view on the analysis of change from baseline adjusted for baseline?

Tags: regression, panel-data, pre-post-comparison, baseline

I always thought, that mathematics, thus statistics, are both strict sciences. So, two mathematicians cannot speak about the same topic and have contrary views on it.

In the pharmaceutical industry, the official, formal guildelines say, that the adjustment for baseline should be added when modelling the change from baseline. Yes, the baseline is put at the same time on both sides of the model. Here it doesn't have any interpretation, just serves to lower the unexplained variance.
[Is there any formal guideline that would indicate the necessity for adjustment for baseline when analysing change from baseline?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459279/is-there-any-formal-guideline-that-would-indicate-the-necessity-for-adjustment-f?rq=1)

But at the same time, other statisticians say, that:

1. it makes no sense to have baseline value at both sides of the equation
2. y1-y0 is correlated with y0 ( [How to adress the -0.71 correlation artefact in the pre-post analysis of change from baseline in non-randomized trials?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487274/how-to-adress-the-0-71-correlation-artefact-in-the-pre-post-analysis-of-change) )

[Is there a mathematical proof for change being correlated with baseline value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/478310/is-there-a-mathematical-proof-for-change-being-correlated-with-baseline-value)

[Difference between Repeated measures ANOVA, ANCOVA and Linear mixed effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476176/difference-between-repeated-measures-anova-ancova-and-linear-mixed-effects-mode/476368#476368)

And this topic is just a "masterpiece" - all contrary responses in a single thread: [Is it valid to include a baseline measure as control variable when testing the effect of an independent variable on change scores?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/is-it-valid-to-include-a-baseline-measure-as-control-variable-when-testing-the-e/15795#comment28442_15719)

The same discrepancy is about using the post-value-adjusted-for-baseline ANCOVA vs. change-for-baseline-adjusted-for-baseine ANCOVA: lots of articles, including regulatory guidelines(!) saying that the analysis of change is mandatory in non-randomized trials, while other articles claim, that this is absolutely not true.

It's a madness. Same topic, totally different opinions of qualified statisticians, also from the regulatory agencies. What's wrong with that? I come from an industry, where the baseline MUST be included in the change and as a covariate. My colleague, econometrician says that this approach is "flawed at its ground".

One says: "it totally doesn't address" vs. "it exactly addresses".

Is there any common opinion about this topic, finally?