# Different ways to include pre-test performance as a covariate in a linear mixed-effect regression. Which is correct?

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, ancova, lsmeans

I have a pre-post experimental design, where I have measured participants' performance in three courses (tasks; A, B, C) at both pre and post-test. The study is a learning experiment. 60 elite alpine skiers have practised 12 runs in each of the three courses (A, B, C). One group have practised these courses in 'random' order, e.g., 'ABC, whereas the other group have practised these courses in a blocked order, e.g. 'AAA, BBB, CCC. I want to build a model to test whether the 'random' group performed better on post-test when controlling for pre-test performance. So the pre-test is just an earlier version of their performance. The data structure looks like this:

| subjectID | Course | Group | pre-test.score | post-test.score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ii | ### | # |
| 1 | B | ii | ### | # |
| 1 | C | ii | ### | # |
| 2 | A | b | ### | # |
| 2 | B | b | ### | # |
| 2 | C | b | ### | # |

I have analysed these data using a linear mixed-effect regression model where I predict post-test performance, controlling for pre-test performance with the + sign:

```
# I fit these models with lmer in R
CI_post <- lmer(
  post ~ 
    pre +
    group * course 
  + (1|subjectID) , 
  data = dat, 
  REML = FALSE)
```

Using Satterthwaite's method from the **emmeans** package I get:

```
CI_post_interaction_coursegroup <- emmeans(CI_post, specs = c("course", "group"),lmer.df = "satterthwaite")

course group       emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A      blocked      0.311 0.191 6.65  -0.1452    0.768
 B      blocked      0.649 0.180 5.38   0.1954    1.102
 C      blocked      1.141 0.195 7.28   0.6847    1.598
 A      interleaved  0.189 0.194 7.15  -0.2666    0.645
 B      interleaved  0.497 0.179 5.31   0.0451    0.949
 C      interleaved  1.046 0.191 6.72   0.5907    1.502
```

But I could perhaps also perform the same model adding pre-test with as an interaction term to the model, so that that the model becomes **pre.test * course * group**

```
CI_post <- lmer(
  post ~ 
    pre *
    group * course 
  + (1|subjectID),
  data = dat, 
  REML = FALSE)
```

, which gives very different estimates:

```
 course group        emmean    SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
 A      blocked     -0.0669 0.188 11.10   -0.481    0.347
 B      blocked      0.6466 0.161  6.09    0.255    1.038
 C      blocked      1.1980 0.194 12.65    0.778    1.618
 A      interleaved -0.1520 0.211 16.76   -0.597    0.293
 B      interleaved  0.4872 0.160  6.12    0.098    0.876
 C      interleaved  1.0593 0.181  9.82    0.654    1.464
```

I am trying to understand the exact differences between these two models, and which is them is "correct"?. Long (see comments below) gave a helpful comment that "if you want the group:course interaction to vary depending on the value of pre then you fit the 2nd model with the 3-way interaction". But since my pre-test score is a continuous variable that measured each participant's performance on **course A**, **course B** and **course C**, will the model use this data structure when I add an interaction term between the covariate and factors in the model?

Comment: The difference is that one has a 2-way interaction and the other has a 3-way interaction, making the two models completely different. If you want the `group:course` interaction to vary depending on the value of `pre.diff` then you fit the 2nd model with the 3-way interaction.

Comment: Thanks, Long. What exactly do you mean by the "value of pre.diff" in my case?

Comment: I mean exactly that- I don't know any other way to say it. When you have a 3-way interaction, this means that the 2-way interaction varies depending on the value of the 3rd variable.

Comment: The relationships between `post.diff` or `pre.diff` in your model and the values `pre-test.score` and `post-test.score` in your data aren't clear. Does `post.diff` perhaps represent the difference between `post-test.score` and `pre-test.score`? If so, there might be an additional problem in your analysis beyond your difficulties with interaction terms. Please edit your question to clarify, as comments are easily overlooked and sometimes deleted.

Comment: I have changed it. Post and Pre are the raw observation. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is there a separate `pre` score for each of courses A, B and C, or is the `pre` score some composite score applying to all courses?

Comment: Yes. It is a separate score for each of the courses (A, B and C). I tried to show that in the table

Comment: Both models could be fine and there is not one correct model. The first model assumes that the effect of pre-test on post-test is the same for all groups and courses. The second model assumes that the effect of the pre-test depends on the course *and* the group. Ideally, you would make an educated guess based on the literature and/or subject matter knowledge. You could also compare the models using a likelihood ratio test (or another criterion). In any case, you should probably inspect the residuals to see whether there is evidence for a model misspecification.

Comment: Can you tell us your research question?  What is it you want to use this model to figure out?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks. Great explanation.  For me, it sounds as the interaction model is more appropriate. I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wide variety of interaction terms could be "correct" here, as comments from Robert Long and COOLSerdash suggest. To decide which if any interaction to use involving the `pre` value, you have to think very carefully about how you want to "control for pre-test performance."

**Try `pre-post` difference as outcome**

The first question is whether you might be better off just using the time difference `pre-post` as the outcome measure of improvement following training. That's one perfectly acceptable way to control for pre-test performance. Or, if you expect proportional improvements rather than linear improvements in time with training, use the difference of the logs of `pre` and `post` to get the log of the `pre/post` ratio. (You shouldn't then make the [mistake](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478310/28500)* of continuing to include the `pre` value in your model.) That's the idea behind a paired t-test, just expanded in your situation to include the types of courses and types of training. Expressing the difference in this direction has an advantage in that an increasingly positive outcome value is an improvement in performance, which seems to be of most interest.

That would change the interpretation of the fixed and random effects in your model, but maybe in a way more useful in this application. The `course*group` term would give you how the *improvement itself* depends on each combination of `group` and `course`. The `(1|subjectID)` would represent estimated differences in improvement among individuals at some baseline combination of `group` and `course`.

That approach, if it's reasonable in your application, would greatly simplify both the modeling and explaining results to others.

**Using `pre` as a predictor for `post`, without further interactions.**

Although that's another acceptable way to "control for pre-test performance," it does so in a different way. Your model then is something like:

```
post ~ b0 + b1 * pre + (terms from course, group, their interactions, with associated coefficients)
```

That implies that the `post` value is based around a common intercept `b0` plus an *additive* contribution *proportional to* the `pre` value (the same regardless of the particular combination of `group` and `course` in question) and separate additive contributions from the combination of `group` and `course`. Does that make sense for your application?

**Including `pre` in interactions**

That would take the prior model and expand it to allow the *proportional* contribution of `pre` to `post` to differ depending on `course` and `group` (and vice-versa). You don't need to include all potential interactions with a `pre*course*group` term. That full interaction allows each of the `course*group` interactions to depend *linearly* on the value of `pre`. Is that what you need? Is such a *linear* interaction with the `pre` value reasonable? Might simply allowing for interactions of `pre` with `course` and/or `group` individually (e.g., with `pre:course` and/or `pre:group` terms in R syntax) be enough? Again, there is no "correct" answer in general here, just what makes sense based on your understanding of the subject matter.

**Recommendation**

In general, it can help to write out the full equations for the models including all coefficients and terms rather than just looking at the shorthand of R (or other modeling) syntax. If you do that, you will see just which contributions to outcome are being modified by including particular interaction terms. You can then choose accordingly.

If these are elite Alpine skiers, you presumably are looking at `post-pre` differences on the order of a few seconds, around full `pre` times on the order of many seconds to minutes. In that case, my guess is that the simple t-test-like approach of just using `pre-post` as the outcome while omitting `pre` as a predictor otherwise will work quite well and be much easier to explain to others.

Note that nothing above allows for wipe-outs in `pre` or `post` values or for considering changes in snow-surface or other environmental conditions. That's true for all of these approaches, however.

---

*An [answer from Robert Long](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/478335/28500) on the linked page shows a way to model properly if you think that  the change in performance depends on the `pre` value. In outline, you model the `pre` and `post` values separately, with an indicator variable predictor specifying which of `pre` or `post` is involved.

Comment: (+1). Great explanation. It's worth noticing that using the difference as outcome (without interactions) is akin to including the `pre` values as a predictor for the `post` values but fixing the coefficient at $1$. The model using `pre` as predictor (again without interactions) but estimating the coefficient can be interpreted as modelling an "estimated" or maybe "adjusted" difference between pre and post values.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks. I considered presenting that suggestion as an offset term as you indicate, but thought that the analogy to paired t-tests might be simpler to grasp here.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation. My reason for using the ANCOVA approach (i.e. predicting post with pre as a covariate) was to increase the statistical power of the test.Our approach to 'wipe-out' differences in snow conditions was to do straight gliding runs each day where the skiers ski straight-down the course in a static upright position. Then we subtract the mean time in each of the three courses from the mean time of the straight-gliding runs. That's why my predictors in the model had 'diff' in them. The skiers' goal was to ski faster than their straight-gliding, which they did.

Comment: @Cmagelssen one tradeoff in keeping `pre` values as a predictor instead of just evaluating `pre-post` differences is the increased number of coefficients you have to estimate: at least 1 more if you don't include interactions, then 1 more for each interaction term you include with `pre`. With more coefficients the residual degrees of freedom decrease, and potentially also the precision in coefficient estimates. The question becomes whether any increased power you get with `pre` as a predictor is enough to outweigh the loss of power with more coefficient estimates.

Comment: Good point. So I have to be careful about what I include in the model. I have 64 participants that took part in the experiment.

Comment: @EdM But If I decide to use the ‘interaction model’, wouldn’t that model potentially explain more variance than the additive model? Hence, pre will account for more variance and therefore increase power?

Comment: @Cmagelssen that's the hope. It doesn't always work out that way. It all depends on _how much_ more variance is explained by `pre` (and its interactions), versus the cost from estimating additional coefficients. Interaction terms are especially troublesome, as adding them leads to multiplicatively increasing numbers of coefficients. As with many things in statistical analysis, "it depends" and there's no single "correct" answer that fits all situations. If you want to use `pre` as a predictor, also consider Robert Long's multi-level approach, in the link from the footnote to my answer.