# Subgroup analysis: post hoc test interpretation

Tags: interaction, linear-model, post-hoc, clinical-trials

I am modeling treatment effect in a hypothetical case where only a subset of the sample has disease-related impairment on the outcome of interest. I only expect treatment effects in this subset, but due to variability in the outcome (natural variability + measurement noise), the baseline value of the outcome measure gives me imperfect information about which subjects are impaired (but lower values reflect higher probability of impairment).

My model is `val ~ TRT*baseline`, and fitting this model gives 1) a positive main effect of treatment, 2) a negative main effect of baseline, and 3) a negative TRT:baseline interaction (larger effect of TRT for those with low baseline scores).

Using this model, I would like to run a post hoc test that gives me a single effect estimate (& hypothesis test) for individuals that are impaired. I think that would be `TRT + -1*TRT:baseline`, which would be interpreted as the estimated effect size for a subject with a baseline score of -1. Is that right?

I'm open to suggestions for very different ways to model this scenario, but I'm primarily interested to know that I am not misinterpreting this model.

Here is a simulation in R:

```
library(MASS)
library(multcomp)
library(tidyverse)

# Parameters
n = 10000
trt_efct = 0.5
impairment_prob = 0.5
impairment_ef_sz = 1


res_corr = matrix(
  c(
    1.0, 0.8,
    0.8, 1.0
  ),
  2,2
)

# Simulate data
df = data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(
  n, 
  mu=c(0,0), 
  Sigma=res_corr
)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    subject = 1:n,
    arm = c(rep("TRT", n/2), rep("PBO", n/2)),
    im.flag = stats::runif(n, min = 0, max = 1) >= impairment_prob,
    baseline = dplyr::if_else(im.flag, X1 - impairment_ef_sz, X1),
    val = dplyr::case_when(
      im.flag == 1 & arm == "TRT" ~ (X2 - impairment_ef_sz*(1 - trt_efct)),
      im.flag == 1 & arm == "PBO" ~ (X2 - impairment_ef_sz),
      im.flag == 0 ~ X2
    )
  )

# Fit baseline interaction model: arm * baseline
model_fit = stats::lm(
    val ~ arm*baseline,
    data = df,
  )

summary(model_fit)

summary(multcomp::glht(model_fit, linfct = matrix(c(0,1,0,-1), nrow=1)))
```

Comment: Using a baseline value as a predictor of a change score is not a good idea. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15713/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478310/28500).

Comment: @EdM Modified - better?

Answer (score 1):

If your understanding of the subject matter indicates that a `baseline` score of -1 represents "impaired" individuals, then what you propose is correct (given the ordering of the coefficient estimates in your `model_fit`).

A display of the continuous association of outcome with `baseline` score as a function of treatment might be more useful to your readers. The [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans), for example, simplifies this type of post-modeling calculation without your having to keep track of coefficient numbering.

Although outside my expertise, this situation seems like it might benefit from some joint modeling of `baseline` scores among "impaired" and "non-impaired" individuals along with your hypothesis that the treatment effect is restricted to the "impaired."